# Call function of type void* with arguments of type void*

Tags: c

I have a function which will be called from `main.c`.
Function prototype is

```
void *function (void *args)
{ 
    Struct strData *data = args; 
    char* str;
    int a;
    str = data->name; 
    a = data->value;
    if (data->value == 1)
    { 
        data->value = 10;
        return data;
    }
}
```

And the structure definition is

```
Struct strData
{
    int data;
    char* name;
};
```

How to call above function from main ? And how can I return entire structure to a void* from a function? And how to send the value to arguments? Do I need to typecast the value of argument inside function?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve by calling this function from main? The context is not clear enough yet.

Comment: Why pass `args` as a `void *` and not as a `struct strData *` ?

Comment: Looks like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: It has to be void* Bec it is a generic function being implemented

Comment: This requirement is somewhat strange. You need to tell us more about what you are _actually_ trying to achieve. Passing something as `void*` is highly fishy.

Comment: If data==args is a pointer to strData, then `data->value` seems meaningless. I would expect `data->data`. And checking that `args!=NULL`would not hurt.

Comment: I wanna send structure values to function, based on value of structure elements.. I need to set or reset some parameters

Comment: Okay. I will put the code here.. which includes main also in sometime :) sorry for incomplete information

Comment: You want this: `void *function (struct strData *data) ...`. Using a `void*` is pointless here. And it's `struct`, not `Struct`.

Comment: Did you think of `function(&ExistingStructureOfTheType);` ?

Comment: @Sona and please don't post the whole program but strip it down to a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to answer what you asked:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct strData
{
//changed member name from data to value due to conflicting call in funtion
    int value;
    char* name;
};

//function takes a void pointer as parameter and returns a void pointer
//I don't understand why you have written such code below.
void *function (void *args)
{ 
    struct strData *data = args; 
    char* str;
    int a;
    str = data->name; 
    a = data->value;
    if( data->value == 1)
    {   
        data->value = 10; 
    }   

    //return statement required at the end. Why?
    return data;
}

int main(){
    //created a variable of strData
    struct strData data;
    //initialised random values
    data.value = 1;
    data.name = "stackoverflow.com";
    //pass address of the variable. Why? typecast to struct. Why? Finally get value using *. Why?
    data = *(struct strData*)function(&data);
    printf("%s %d", data.name, data.value);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer all why questions yourself.

Comment: Thanks prince :) What will happen if the struct strData has object of pointer type? Should we send address of &data or only data?

Comment: why don't you try doing both and find out? You will learn a lot by committing mistakes.

Comment: Why do you think it a good idea to change the structure type?  It isn't clear that it is necessary, or even particularly desirable.

Comment: It does not matter actually. I did it only to resolve the conflicting statement data->value = 10;  in the function.

Comment: This code compiles and works, but it is completly pointless to have a `void*` as argument and as return value. There is absolutely no benefit.

Comment: @MichaelWalz exactly. That is why I added that comment before function definition. The code does not really make any sense to me either.